# Custom homepage with recent blog posts

Tags: themes, child-theme, homepage, blog

I have a self-hosted site on wordpress.com - I have been told it isn't self-hosted.

Basically, I have my own domain but use Wordpress as a platform.
I am currently trying to create a home page where there the home page contains latest blog posts as well as sliders, image galleries etc.

I don’t want the latest blog posts to be on the sidebar, I want it to be as it would be if I had selected “latest posts”. I have added the content view plugin and it is closer to what I want but still not quite there yet. I would like to change the font size/style, positioning of title etc. but I am unable to do this. Ideally, would like blog posts to be in a vertical format rather than a grid or the most recent post as the main post then the other recent posts in chronological order in a grid format such as https://demo.wpzoom.com/?theme=foodica

Can anyone help?

Any plugins/widgets would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "a self-hosted site on wordpress.com" Can't be both, self-hosted is the opposite of WordPress.com. Who's your host?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Theoretically this is not necessarily true any more since wordpress.com introduced the Business plan https://wordpress.com/business which gives you more access to install plugins and themes almost like normal self hosting.

Comment: Doesn't make it "self-hosted".

Comment: Self-hosted site VS wordpress.com ... FYI : If it's on wordpress.com, it's not  in self-hosted site.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the correct terms. I have my own domain and web hosting and I am using Wordpress for my blogging.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Page Builder](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/). If you don't know much about Wordpress then you can use this for designing your pages.

If you want to customize the theme (edit font size, colour, etc) then try creating [Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried using this but how do I make the big post the most recent post and how do I make the grid posts the next most recent one? Is there a widget or plugin for that?